# asymptotic behavior with two different conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I proved for a real sequence $\{a_n\}$ that $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sim C \log( N)$  as $N \to \infty$ if $a_n \sim C/n$.

Using Cesaro-Stolz theorem I got
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}{\log (N)} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{a_{N+1}}{\log (N+1)-\log(N)} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{(N+1)a_{N+1}}{(N+1)\log (1+1/N)}\\ = \frac{\lim_{N \to \infty}(N+1)a_{N+1} }{\lim_{N \to \infty}\log (1+1/N)^{N+1} } = C$$

Is this also true if $\sum_{n=1}^N na_n \sim CN$ and how is it proved?

Comment: Fixed Typo    ..............

Comment: So you proved that if $a_n$'s have a certain asymptotics then the partial sums have one. Now you assume that the partial sums have an asymptotics and you want to prove what?

Comment: @gary I proved the second condition implies the first condition. Now I want to show if the last condition implies the first condition which is $\sum a_n \sim C\log N$